# How to delete extra lines in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Does somebody know how to delete these lines in the last non-existing column in the WPF DataGrid? And also how to remove the last extra row?

[image]

Here is my xaml:

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

<Border BorderBrush="#FF333333" BorderThickness="1">
    <DataGrid Name="ParametersConfigGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Loaded="ParametersConfigGrid_OnLoaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order" Binding="{Binding Order}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter Name" Binding="{Binding ParameterName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Designation" Binding="{Binding Designation}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Border>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to stick to datagridview ?

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the last row, in your DataGrid set the `CanUserAddRows` property to False:

```
<DataGrid Name="ParametersConfigGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          Loaded="ParametersConfigGrid_OnLoaded"
          CanUserAddRows="False">
```

To get rid of the lines that extend past your columns, use a row style. You can just put the style into your Window Resources.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

You may need to add a style for the cells if you want borders on cells. You would do it in a very similar way as for the row.